# Error: A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: facebook, typescript, firebase, plugins, nativescript

I follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IextEpoIzwE). This app I run in a mobile devixe Xiaomi Redmi 4A.
Install succesfully and show this error. I can't understand why? I can't use Facebook in this code.

Error:

> Successfully synced application org.nativescript.pushnotify on device
>   8066aa497d24. ActivityManager: Start proc
>   26158:org.nativescript.pushnotify/u0a238 for activity
>   org.nativescript.pushnotify/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity caller=null
>   07-06 12:21:32.247 26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:
>   com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1101) 07-06
>   12:21:32.247 26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:983) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:970) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:954) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:946) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:
>   com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1101) 07-06
>   12:21:32.247 26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:983) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:970) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:954) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:946) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1101) 07-06
>   12:21:32.247 26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:983) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:970) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:954) 07-06 12:21:32.247
>   26158 26158 E AndroidRuntime:        at
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:946) System.err:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.pushnotify/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}:
>   com.tns.NativeScriptException: System.err: Calling js method onCreate
>   failed System.err: System.err: Error: A valid Facebook app id must be
>   set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling
>   FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk. System.err: 
>   com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:276)
>   System.err:
>   com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:232)
>   System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
>   System.err:
>   com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1101)
>   System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:983)
>   System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:970)
>   System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:954)
>   System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:946)
>   System.err:
>   com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:18)
>   System.err:     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6875)
>   System.err:
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>   System.err:
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
>   System.err:
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
>   System.err:
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) System.err:
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
>   System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) System.err:
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221) System.err: 
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) System.err:
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>   System.err:
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>   System.err: File:
>   "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.js,
>   line: 331, column: 41 System.err: System.err: StackTrace: System.err: 
>   Frame: function:'runInit',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.js',
>   line: 331, column: 42 System.err:     Frame:
>   function:'Observable.notify',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js',
>   line: 110, column: 23 System.err:     Frame: function:'notifyLaunch',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
>   line: 870, column: 17 System.err:     Frame:
>   function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
>   line: 803, column: 28 System.err:     Frame:
>   function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
>   line: 677, column: 14 System.err:     Frame:
>   function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js',
>   line: 20, column: 25 System.err: System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2706)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) System.err:
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) System.err:
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221) System.err: 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>   System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>   System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: System.err:
>   Calling js method onCreate failed System.err: System.err: Error: A
>   valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by
>   calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.
>   System.err:
>   com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:276)
>   System.err:
>   com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:232)
>   System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
>   System.err:
>   com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1101)
>   System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:983)
>   System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:970)
>   System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:954)
>   System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:946)
>   System.err:
>   com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:18)
>   System.err:     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6875)
>   System.err:
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>   System.err:
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
>   System.err:
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
>   System.err:
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) System.err:
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
>   System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) System.err:
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221) System.err: 
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) System.err:
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>   System.err:
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>   System.err: File:
>   "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.js,
>   line: 331, column: 41 System.err: System.err: StackTrace: System.err: 
>   Frame: function:'runInit',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase.js',
>   line: 331, column: 42 System.err:     Frame:
>   function:'Observable.notify',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js',
>   line: 110, column: 23 System.err:     Frame: function:'notifyLaunch',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
>   line: 870, column: 17 System.err:     Frame:
>   function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
>   line: 803, column: 28 System.err:     Frame:
>   function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
>   line: 677, column: 14 System.err:     Frame:
>   function:'NativeScriptActivity.onCreate',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.pushnotify/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js',
>   line: 20, column: 25 System.err: System.err:     at
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method) System.err:     at
>   com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1101)
>   System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:983)
>   System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:970)
>   System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:954)
>   System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:946)
>   System.err:     at
>   com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:18)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6875) System.err:
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
>   System.err:     ... 9 more System.err: Caused by: A valid Facebook app
>   id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling
>   FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk. System.err: 
>   at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:276)
>   System.err:     at
>   com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:232)
>   System.err:     ... 19 more ActivityManager: report kill process:
>   killerPid is:26158, killedPid is:26158 ActivityManager: Process
>   org.nativescript.pushnotify (pid 26158) has died: fore TS
>   ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 26158

Can you ask me any idea please? How to solution this?

Comment: The plugin nativescript-plugin-firebase has evolved and changed a lot since 2016 (when the video was shot) - follow the instruction from the README https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/AUTHENTICATION.md

Comment: And maybe get used to that in general - _reading up_ on stuff in the primary sources, instead of watching videos …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your AndroidManifest should contain this line `<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>`

Here is a partial AndroidManifest.xml containing it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="__PACKAGE__"
      android:versionCode="10017"
      android:versionName="1.17">
...
    <application android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
             android:allowBackup="true"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        ...
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And in your `App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`, set the facebook application ID starting with `fb`

```
<resources>
    ...
    <string name="facebook_app_id">fb{{ facebook_app_id }}</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: But this set `_fbSourceApplicationHasBeenSet` to `bundle` GLOBALLY, and so `bundle` is never `null` which causes a player library crash, so I need set app id in java but not manifest. Any idea ?